# Installing berks on centos

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, berkshelf, berksfile

I am trying to install berks on centos using command:

```
[root@ip~]#gem install berkshelf --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

After installing I have verified whether berks have been installed using the command:

```
[root@ip~]# berks -v
-bash: berks: command not found
```

Also I would like to tell you that I am using ruby that comes shipped with Chef. I have not installed ruby explicitly on system.

I would like to know how to install berks on centos.

Any lead in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I have already put so much efforts to set up the environment ie. the server workstation. It would be a big pain for mr to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CentOS probably has it's own system Ruby. When you run:

```
$ which gem
```

You will likely see:

```
/bin/ruby
```

or something similar. That is **not** Chef's Ruby. In order to use the `gem` command that is bundled in Chef's Ruby, you need to specify the full path:

```
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install berkshelf --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Then, the binstub is installed into Chef's Ruby, so running `berks` will not work directly. You need to specify the full path:

```
$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/berks -v
```

Please also make sure the installation of Berkshelf completes successfully. If the gem (or one of its dependencies) fails to install, the binstub will not be present.

You can avoid all this extra typing by adding `/opt/chef/embedded/bin` to your `$PATH`:

```sh
# ~/.bashrc
export PATH="/opt/chef/embedded/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: hey I have installed berkshelf. using the above command. now what to do next. do i need to install it or do i need to set the environmnetal variable ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.